# Зачет аванса на ККТ

Tags: python, касса, ккт

Как правильно сформировать документ для кассы в следующих случаях? Можно ли это оформить в одном чеке?

Частичная оплата с передачей товара - сумма оплат меньше суммы документа. Если я поставю операцию "передача в кредит" и добавлю оплаты на документ пройдет ли чек?

Переплата по документу: добавляю строку с суммой переплаты и признаком аванс. Как зачесть этот аванс правильно в следующей сделке?

Операции передаются через новый формат https://github.com/alex-eri/pyshtrih/blob/84fe546bd141b92c5e66c7f35a6969e38d405d18/pyshtrih/commands.py#L869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нет. В любом случае пробиваются два чека, или аванс и полный расчет, либо кредит и затем оплата кредита.
2. Ваш вариант возможен, но в "главкниге" пишут:

> Должны предупредить, что официальных разъяснений о правомерности такого «упрощенного» варианта оформления чеков при зачете переплаты мы не нашли и неизвестно, как его воспримут проверяющие из налоговой.
> https://glavkniga.ru/elver/2019/18/4347-ispolizuem_onlajn_kassu_pravilino.html